# jQuery mobile, show message when form element input type="range" value is max

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a form in jQuery mobile and using form element input type="range". When max value is picked I want a message to show something like "Ok, this value or more" in a span underneath. A generic function that supports multiple ranges would be most useful. How can such a function be made?

```
<label>Highest price?
    <input type="range" name="highest_price" id="highest_price" data-highlight="true" step="500" value="38000" min="2000" max="40000" size="29"/>
</label>
```

---

Here's an option I put together that's a function and works with multiple range fields in a form. Could be improved with $(document).on('slidestop' etc..

```
<label>Highest price?
    <input type="range" name="highest_price" id="highest_price" data-highlight="true" step="500" value="38000" min="2000" max="40000" size="29"/>
</label>
<label>When?
    <input type="range" name="withindays" id="withindays" data-highlight="true" step="1" value="5" min="1" max="20" size="29"/>
</label>

<script>
//Gives msg when value is max in range
function nyakilian_range_max_msg (thisinput){
    thisinputspan = thisinput+'_span';
    thisinput = '#' + thisinput;
    maxvalue = jQuery(thisinput).attr('max');
    slider_value = jQuery(thisinput).val();
    if(slider_value == maxvalue){   
        jQuery('#'+thisinputspan).fadeIn();
        jQuery('#form_search_txrn_milage_span').fadeIn();
    } else {  
        jQuery('#'+thisinputspan).hide();
    }
}
function nyakilian_range_max_msg_init(thisinput, mess) {
    jQuery('#'+ thisinput).parent().change( function() {
        nyakilian_range_max_msg(thisinput);
    });
    jQuery('#'+ thisinput).after('<span id="' + thisinput + '_span" style="display: none;">'+mess+'</span>');
}

nyakilian_range_max_msg_init('highest_price', 'Alright that\'s max! ');
nyakilian_range_max_msg_init('withindays', 'Alright before that or later! ');

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/an7Ax/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    nyakilian_range_max_msg_init('#highest_price', 'Alright that\'s max! ');
    nyakilian_range_max_msg_init('#withindays', 'Alright before that or later! ');     
});

function nyakilian_range_max_msg_init(thisinput, msg) {
    $(document).on('slidestop', thisinput, function(){ 
        if($(this).val() == $(thisinput).attr('max')) {
            $(this).parent().after('<span class="slider-msg">'+ msg +'</span>');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.slider-msg').fadeIn();
        } else {
            if($(this).parent().parent().find('.slider-msg').length > 0 ) {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.slider-msg').fadeOut().remove();
            }
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Just a thought may be we can add `<font color='red'>Ok, this price ... </font>` since its an error kind of thing.

Comment: This is just a proof of concept. Carl can style it according to his needs, but I like your idea.

Comment: Regarding your update, look at my example again, I will update my answer. And tell me if this is it.